# Product modeling

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, subdivision-surface, bevel, boolean-modifier

This is Smit from India. I am stuck somewhere while modeling a product. It is not so complex but I am new in Blender so I am finding difficulties rn. Looking forward to having a solution.

Product description:
It is a cube with round edges.
It's length, width and height are different (not much difference).
It is a little broad from the bottom (/_\ kinda look like this).
It has 3 holes on the sides. Headphone jack, type C and a hole for button.

Major issue:
Somewhat dense mesh.
Boolean cutting.
Clamps in cycle render.
Confused with subd modeling.

I haven't make it using subd modeling and the mesh has become slightly complex but when I tried subd modeling method, I couldn't make it. Found the above issues.

Thanks.

[image: This is headphone jack and there will be a button on the opposite face.]

[image: And here goes the type C port which I didn't , make right now.]

Comment: Sorry but this is not a tutorial site and you should only ask about one issue for each question. You haven't given any details of how you got to the stage you are at or what problems you are actually having. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and try again.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.